# consoleのログからPHPに渡したい

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

各々は正常に稼働するのですが、AdVideoCompleteを拾ってつなげていく方法が何度やっても上手くいかずご質問させていただいてる次第です。

ajaxでPHPに渡してやるのがいいとは思うのですが、javascriptで可能なのかもしれませんが、ajaxをあまり触ったことがなく孤軍奮闘したのですが解決できませんでした。

```
<script>
function init (api) {
if (api) {
api.on('AdStarted', function()
{console.log('AdStarted')}
);
api.on('AdVideoComplete', function()
{console.log('AdVideoComplete')}
);
} else
{ console.log('blank'); }
}
</script>
function syori(){
document.getElementById('PhotoSpace').src = 'https://〇〇〇〇.jp/point/img/{point}point.jpg';
var link = document.getElementById("cmlink");
link.href = "./〇〇〇.php?m={md5}";
}
```

Comment: 頂いたソースコードはこれが全てでしょうか？というのもapiの部分もなく、Ajaxの処理部分も書いていないように理解しました。[最小限の・自己完結した・確認可能なサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)を参考に、最低限動く状況になるようにコードを修正いただけると良いと思います。

Answer (score 1):

XMLHttpRequest（Ajax）のスクリプトが知りたいようなので、参考まで
詳しくは、https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest　などを見て下さい。

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open("GET", "〇〇〇.php?m=12345", true);

xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    switch (xhr.readyState) {
        case 0:
            //状態: 未初期化
            break;
        case 1: //状態: データ送信中
            break;
        case 2: //状態: 応答待ち
            break;
        case 3: //状態: データ受信中.
            // console.log(xhr.responseText.length+'bytes' );
            break;
        case 4: //状態: データ受信完了.
            if (this.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status == 200) {
                // 送信後処理
            }
            break;
    }
}

xhr.send();
```